# An error in "stack build" of haskell which doesn't make sense

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

So far, for weeks, everything has been ok. But all of a sudden "stack build" has begun returning this (obfuscated a bit):

```
$ stack build
MyLib-0.1.0.1: build
Preprocessing library MyLib-0.1.0.1...
[53 of 55] Compiling Web.MyLib.SomeFile.MyFile ( src/Web/MyLib/SomeFile/MyFile.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Web/MyLib/SomeFile/MyFile.o )
In-place registering MyLib-0.1.0.1...
Preprocessing executable 'MyLib-exe' for MyLib-0.1.0.1...
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/MyLib-exe/MyLib-exe ...
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/MyLib-exe/MyLib-exe-tmp/Main.o:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `fdsfdzuC6HIw1NjUcr0zzrqlCnCP5y_WebziMyLibziSomeFileziMyFile_MyFileGetSingle1_info'
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/MyLib-exe/MyLib-exe-tmp/Main.o: In function `S6VL_srt':
(.data+0xe8): undefined reference to `fdsfdzuC6HIw1NjUcr0zzrqlCnCP5y_WebziMyLibziSomeFileziMyFile_MyFileGetSingle1_closure'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

--  While building package MyLib-0.1.0.1 using:
      /home/me123/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build lib:MyLib exe:MyLib-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I've done "stack update, upgrade" but it's not helped.

Comment: Try run `stack clean` and delete the `.stack-work` folder at your project root. I fixed some of my building issues by doing so.

Comment: on a first glance this look like you forgot to put an module in the ` exposed-modules` list in the cabal-file (you can use `other-modules` too - but they have to go in one or the other AFAIK)

Comment: @Carsten, it's there.

Comment: what do you men with "it's there"? Is `Web.MyLib.SomeFile.MyFile` in `exposed-modules` (for the lib - not for your executable)? - Please post your `.cabal` and your folder-structure

Comment: @Carsten, yes, it's in exposed-modules. moreover, as I said, so far it's compiled well, for weeks.

Comment: well then sorry but I'm afraid that there is just not enough information to remote-debug your problem - have you tried to clean up the build artifacts as zakyggaps proposed?

Comment: Also if you a minimal example somewhere I can grab it I could try to look at it for you.

Comment: There's a known [non-deterministic issue with `ld`](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#i-get-strange-ld-errors-about-recompiling-with-fpic). I'm not sure whether your problem is related. There's a suggested workaround [in this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3qv1rl/a_link_error_in_haskellr/). Does that work for you?